# Tiny MCE Editor - Icons are not coming in Firefox

Tags: javascript, tinymce, cross-domain

Am using TinyMCE editor in my website. It works well in Chrome but not in Firefox. When i check firefox console it says the following...

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://www.example.com/VisualServe/siteadmin/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray/fonts/tinymce.woff.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

But i have the font files in the same domain only. i mean its all there in http://www.example.com/ only.

Can someone tell how to fix it ? Its happening only in Firefox. In chrome its working well.

Thanks,

Comment: If you're using the examples from TinyMCE, a lot of their samples use a CDN. Make sure you don't have a reference to the CDN in one of your instances

Comment: No sir. you can see my file is referring to my local website... i do not refer to their CDN. The firebug console is giving the above error where it says 'Cross-Origin Request blocked' even though the tinymce.woff file is in my local server ... or do i need to modify anything in tinymce.woff ?

Comment: i solved it by using CDN... I have added <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script> instead adding js from my local server... and it worked now...